# Apache server log highest traffic using bash

Tags: apache, bash

I have an Apache server log and am trying to determine what IP address has generated the most traffic. I've already managed to get it formatted so its just the IPs and their traffic in bytes:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 915925
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy 1193
zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz 2356
```

So now I'm looking for a method to combine and add the bytes of identical IPs and then just find the top value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ip and traffic bytes in a file use the following to get the work done.

1. **`cat file | perl -ane '$h{ $F[0] } += $F[1]; END { for ( sort keys %h ) { printf qq[%s %d\n], $_, $h{ $_ } } }' | sort -k2 -n -r`**
2. **`awk '{A[$1]+=$2;next}END{for(i in A){print i,A[i]}}' file | sort -k2 -n -r`**